# Adding values of common field to field during union?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, union

I have 3 overlay features; A,B,C and each has a field called FIELD_ID

If I do a union, I will get 3 new fields in the output: FIELD_ID_1, FIELD_ID_2, FIELD_ID_3

But how do I get just one summary field 'FIELD_SUMMARY' that contains the values of FIELD_ID_1, FIELD_ID_2, FIELD_ID_3 for each polygon?

How do I list the values of [FIELD_ID] for features A,B and C  that occur from the union but in a single field, not multiple ones?

I'm aware that I can do a field calculation after the union that will concatenate values from FIELD_ID_1, FIELD_ID_2, FIELD_ID_3 etc, but that seems a bit long winded

Answer (score 1):

I think your "long winded" way of using the Field Calculator to concatenate the field values into a new field may be your best bet.

If you are comfortable with cursors then using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor() to concatenate the field values into a new field is an alternative but the principle is the same.

I would not expect an out-of-the-box tool for something like this because there are many ways that the multiple fields could be combined, and leaving it to Field Calculator or an Update Cursor gives you the flexibility to decide how you want to combine them.